# Confirm Message on DropDown Select Change

Tags: onchange, confirm

I need to show a Confirm message when the value Hiring is selected in the dropdown. How can I do that?

```
if (Status.SelectedValue == "HIRING")
    {
       Status.Attributes.Add("onChange", "javascript:return DisplayConfirmation();");
    }
```

I have the function DisplayConfirmation in aspx page. This does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Alter the DisplayConfirmation() javascript function to include a parameter for the selected value, and handle the logic inside the function.

In the Code behind, replace your code with this:

```
Status.Attributes.Add("OnChange", string.Format("DisplayConfirmation('{0}');", Status.SelectedValue));
```

So, you can change your javascript to be

```
function DisplayConfirmation(Status) { 
 if(Status == "HIRING")
{
 if (confirm('Are you sure you want to do this?')) { __doPostback('Status', ''); } 
  }}
```

Comment: function DisplayConfirmation() {
if (confirm('Are you sure you want to do this?')) {
__doPostback('Status', '');
 } This is the function I'm using but it doesn't seem to be working.
}